# Trigger click event on parent but prevent click event on children

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, event-propagation

I have two events bound to two objects, one inside the other, with the same size. Let's call it `container` and `content`. Both events head to a different function. The event on `content` is set by default and as I can't remove it I need a way to prevent it (or temporarily unset it).

**I would like that clicking on them only the event related to the `container` gets triggered**. Is possible or not. What is the *best way* to achieve it?

Here below the example. If everything works, clicking the white square should turn green, otherwise it turns red.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#container', goGreen )
$(document).on('click', '#content', goRed )


function goGreen( event )
{
  $('#content').addClass('green')
  showClasses()
  // Now stop!!! 
  // Don't run the click event on #content!!!
}

function goRed( event )
{
  $('#content').addClass('red')
  showClasses()
}

function showClasses()
{
  $('#classes').html( $('#content').attr('class') )
}
```

```css
#content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.red {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <a id="content"></a>
</div>

<p id="classes"></p>
```

Comment: use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from bubbling up to parent

Comment: I think I'm looking for the other way around. Stopping child to and going directly to parent.

Comment: If I understood correctly, this means `click` handler on `content` will never get triggered. Am I right ?

Comment: @abhishekkannojia yep, right

Comment: Then you can stop the event handling in the `content` listener itself.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia how to?

Comment: @a.barbieri See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comment you want to stop the `goRed` method for certain condition then do this inside your function.

```
if(event.target.id=='content') return; // Add your condition here and return.
```

Instead of the `event.target.id=='content'` condition check for your condition when you want it to execute.

**UPDATE**

You can check this condition `$(this).parent().is('#container')` to check if your content is inside `container`.

**SNIPPET**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#container', goGreen )
$(document).on('click', '.content', goRed )


function goGreen( event )
{
  $(this).find('.content').addClass('green')
}

function goRed( event )
{
  if($(this).parent().is('#container')) return; // Add your condition here and return.
  $(this).addClass('red')
}
```

```css
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#container{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  border:2px solid red;
}

.green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.red {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <a class="content"></a>
</div>

<a class="content"></a>
```

Comment: I was looking to *pass through* the `content` so the square gets just the function the makes it green.

Comment: @a.barbieri then you don't want any click on content at all??

Comment: When do you want click on content to be triggered?

Comment: Your question makes sense. In the real application I have two situations: one in which I need the event click on `content` to work and another in which I don't.The event on `content` is always present whereas the one on `container` is initiated only under certain condition.

Comment: @a.barbieri I have added a condtion check if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent further execution of the event that was fired. Here is a working demo that will help you out: https://jsfiddle.net/uogt1tp7/

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use css and apply on the content `pointer-events: none`, but keep in mind that this will disable all pointer events on that element.

Answer (score 1):

As clarified from your comments you don't want the handler on `content` to be executed but you want the event to bubble up to parent. In that case you can stop the event handling in the `content` listener function itself. (Though I feel like you shouldn't have the listener on `content` at all since you are not executing it)

```js
$(document).on('click', '#container', goGreen )
$(document).on('click', '#content', goRed )


function goGreen( event )
{
  $('#content').addClass('green')
  showClasses()
  // Now stop!!! 
  // Don't run the click event on #content!!!
}

function goRed( event )
{
  if(event.target.id === 'content')
    return;
  $('#content').addClass('red')
  showClasses()
}

function showClasses()
{
  $('#classes').html( $('#content').attr('class') )
}
```

```css
#content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.red {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <a id="content"></a>
</div>

<p id="classes"></p>
```

Comment: Listener on `content` is set at the beginning of the script that's the reason for which I need to prevent it if there's a situation in which `content` gets wrapped by a `container`. Event on `container` is set only when that situation appears. That's why I have that listener.

Comment: I cannot accept two answer, but I up-voted yours. Thanks again